# PHP function without any process or code inside

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

While navigating the Zend Framework 2 files, I found some functions like this one :

```
public function fault($fault = null, $code = 404);
```

Why we need to define this kind of function without any process, or code ?

Comment: Probably because something else extends it and what you found is just method's signature, not implementation.

Answer (score 1):

If I look at your example, you are looking at an interface file. Interfaces need implementation by classes that chose to implement it. The file you are looking at is the `Zend\Server\Server` class, which is implemented for example by `Zend\XmlRpc\Server`.

If you look at that class, you'll see that `fault()` has been implemented in there.

More information about interfaces can be found here: [php.net documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.interfaces.php)

Answer (score 0):

### [Zend_Json_Server](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.json.server.html)

`fault($fault = null, $code = 404, $data = null)`

Create and return a  **Zend_Json_Server_Error object**.

**[Zend_Json_Server and how to call it via JSON](http://www.joeyrivera.com/2011/zend_json_server-and-how-to-call-it-via-json-rpc-2-0/)**

Comment: This is Zend Framework 1, the question was about Zend Framework 2.

Comment: See the logo by clicking on ZEND_JSON_SERVER

Comment: See the version, ZF2 doesn't use underscores anymore. They use namespaces.